# How to convert String into Hex nodejs

Tags: node.js, string, hex

I was looking for some standard function like hex to string but inverse,
I want to convert String to Hex, but I only found this [function](https://snipplr.com/view/52975)...

```
// Example of convert hex to String
hex.toString('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In NodeJS, use [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings) to convert string to hex.

```
Buffer.from('hello world', 'utf8').toString('hex');
```

Simple example about how it works:

```
const bufferText = Buffer.from('hello world', 'utf8'); // or Buffer.from('hello world')
console.log(bufferText); // <Buffer 68 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f 72 6c 64>

const text = bufferText.toString('hex');
// To get hex
console.log(text); // 68656c6c6f20776f726c64

console.log(bufferText.toString()); // or toString('utf8')
// hello world

//one single line
Buffer.from('hello world').toString('hex')
```

Comment: I have a base64 string that contains a colon and when I converted it to hex then back to base64 it would strip off the colon. This fixed it thanks!

Comment: This works in `react-native` just need to install `yarn add buffer`

Comment: To have an evenly spaced, 2-letter output, one can just do the following: `Buffer.from('hello world', 'utf8').toString('hex').replace(/../g, '$& ')`

Answer (score 8):

You can use function like the below:

```
  function stringToHex(str) {

  //converting string into buffer
   let bufStr = Buffer.from(str, 'utf8');

  //with buffer, you can convert it into hex with following code
   return bufStr.toString('hex');

   }

 stringToHex('some string here');
```

Answer (score 2):

NPM [amrhextotext](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amrhextotext), simple converter text to hex and hex to text

### **Install**

```
npm i amrhextotext
```

### **Usange:**

```
const text = 'test text'
const hex = '746573742074657874'

const convert = require('amrhextotext')

//convert text to hex
let hexSample = convert.textToHex(text)
//Result: 746573742074657874

//Convert hex to text
let textSample = convert.hexToUtf8(hex)
//Result: test text
```

> **note**: Source from page

Comment: Hi Diego welcome to SO, maybe you can add a link to the package or even adding an example how to use it

Answer (score 0):

If you want a pretty hex string of numbers plotted with 0x prefix :

```
export function toHexString(value: Buffer | number[]): string {
  if(!value) return null;
  if(typeof value == "object") value = Buffer.from(value);
  return value.toString('hex').match(/.{1,2}/g).map(val => `0x${val}`).join(", ");
}
```